# Difference between XSD Simple element and XSD Complex element

Tags: xsd

I Googled this Question but still i'm unable to find the best difference for the Simple **XSD** (XML Schema Definition) Element and Complex XSD Element.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: From Google's [first page](https://www.google.de/search?q=simple+xsd+complex+type&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=BfEJWeKrEI7Z8Afl7J3QBA): [Simple and complex types in XML Schema](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/03/16/simple-and-complex-types-in-xml-schema/)

Comment: @ceving I've read that but i want  brief information.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, why I answer this. But...

> To summarize,
>
> - simple types can only have content directly contained between the element’s opening and closing tags. They cannot have attributes or child elements.
> - complex types can have attributes, can contain other elements, can contain a mixture of elements and text, etc etc.

One is a single value and the other a compound value.